# Start activity with MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to start an activity when screenshot taken, for this i use MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE in my android manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".ScreenshotActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE" />
            <data android:path="/sdcard/pictures/screenshots"
                android:host="localhost"
                android:scheme="file" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This dosent't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` is a broadcast action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE). The system does not use it to start an activity. Hence, the screenshot-taking functionality will not launch your activity.